# How to check Html.radiobuttonfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, razor, radiobuttonfor

I have three radio buttons like the following code in my MVC project.

I need to check one of them when user come back to the page through a back button in my application.

I already save the user's response in Session (like `Session ("MyField") = model.MyField`)

Can you please help me how I can do that?

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.MyField, "Yes")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.MyField, "No")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.MyField, "NA")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you click the browser back button, you will be able to see the input field items with previously submitted data.

If you want to pre select a specific radio button when the page loads, you can set this in your GET action

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var vm= new YourViewModel();
   vm.MyField = "No";  // Replace this hard coded value with whatever value you want to set
   return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shyju, now that I have the value in my session, how can I check the radio button which is for that value?

Comment: Instead of hardcoding "No", Read the value from your session variable and set that. Ex : `Session["MyField"] as string;`

Comment: I did, but it doesnt check the radio button. Actually I want my back button to work exactly like browser's back button.

Comment: It should work as long your `Session["MyField"]` returns the one of those 3 strings. Can you put a breakpoint and inspect the value.